# How do I extract a jpeg's EXIF thumbnail using ImageSharp?

Tags: .net-core, thumbnails, exif, imagesharp

I am trying to extract thumbnails from source jpegs and save them to the file system, using the C# ImageSharp library. I see there is some mention of it in the intellisense for the component:
SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Metadata.ExifProfile.CreateThumbnail()

...but I can't seem to find any documentation for it or examples to call it correctly.

I did find this:

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;  

//method code:
Image<TPixel> thumbnail = image.Metadata.ExifProfile.CreateThumbnail<TPixel>();
```

https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Metadata.Profiles.Exif.ExifProfile.html

...but I need to find where the TPixel type is to get it to work. VisualStudio doesn't recognize it and I can't seem to find a namespace or use it correctly:

"The type or namespace name 'TPixel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Legacy Windows .NET Framework could do this for `System.Drawing.Image.Image.GetThumbnailImage()` and it worked pretty well.

EDIT: Using tocsoft's answer, I changed the code to:

```
if (image.Metadata.ExifProfile != null)
{
    Image<Rgba32> thumbnail = image.Metadata.ExifProfile.CreateThumbnail<Rgba32>();

    thumbnail.Save(thumbnailPath, encoder);
}
```

...however, the `image.Metadata.ExifProfile` is null, which is unexpected since I know these source images have EXIF data.

EDIT: Actually, it's working now. Success! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TPixel` would be any of the pixel formats in the `SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats` namespace. But unless you are planning on interoperating with other systems that require the pixel data layed out in memory in specific ways you will likely just want to use `Rgba32`

```
Image<Rgba32> thumbnail = image.Metadata.ExifProfile.CreateThumbnail<Rgba32>();
```

Comment: Oh, so use any of the types listed there, not literally "TPixel"? Rgba32 shows right up! Thanks!